# My backup_system.sh file didn't run under crontab

Tags: shell-script, cron

So i created a script used to backup system, i tested and it worked. 
Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
backup_files="/home /var/spool/mail /etc /root /boot /opt"
dest="/mnt/backup"
day=$(date +%F)
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$day.tgz"
echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo
tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files
echo
echo "Backup finished"
date
ls -lh $dest
```

But when put it in crontab , it didn't work. I used "crontab -e" and put this following command line in there

```
* * * * * /root/backup_system.sh
```

I waited and nothing happend. I don't know where i was wrong.
@I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, the script was changed permission using chmod.

Comment: Don't set it to run with `* * * * *`. Otherwise a new copy will be spawned every minute, _whether or not_ the previous instance has completed. This can lead to output files being overwritten or corrupted by interpolation.

Comment: @roaima Thank you for your advice. I just use that for testing purpose^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your script is not executable (fix that with `chmod +x /root/backup_system.sh`) or the crond isn't running, there's nothing obviously broken in your script that will prevent it from running.

All of the commands you use (`date`, `hostname`, `tar`, and `ls`) should be in `/bin`, which should be in the default PATH....unless you've changed it in your crontab.

The most likely explanation is that you're trying to run this script from a user's crontab rather than root's crontab.  And that user doesn't have read and execute access to the `/root` directory or to the `/root/backup_system.sh` script.

---

BTW, you should always double-quote your variables.  And it's a good idea to use an array variable for variables that contain a list of things (like `$backup_files`).

Here's an improved version of your script which fixes those problems:

```
#!/bin/bash

backup_files=(/home /var/spool/mail /etc /root /boot /opt)
dest='/mnt/backup'
day=$(date +%F)
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$dest/$hostname-$day.tgz"

echo "Backing up ${backup_files[@]} to $archive_file"
date
echo

tar czf "$archive_file" "${backup_files[@]}"

echo
echo "Backup finished"
date

ls -lh "$dest"
```